# jQuery Form Validation not picking up input name

Tags: jquery, forms, validation, plugins

I'm using the [jQuery form validation](https://jqueryvalidation.org) plugin to validate my form. For some reason it's not picking up the names in my form and I haven't been able to figure out why. When I try to validate the code in my JS, I 
am unable to reference the input elements. Here's the code and a screenshot of what's occurring. Any ideas?

[image]

```
<form id="submit-form">
  <label for="app-name-form">
    <input name="app-name-form" type="text" id="app-name-form"/>
    <div class="label-text">App Name</div>
  </label>

  <label for="team-name-form">
    <input type="text" id="team-name-form" name="team-name-form"/>
    <div class="label-text">Team</div>
  </label>

    <label>
          <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Submit" name="saveForm" id="saveForm"/>
    </label>

</form>


<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submit-form").validate({
        rules: {
            app-name-form: "required"
        },
        messages: {
            app-name-form: {
                required: "Enter name pls"
            }
        }
    });
    });

    $('#saveForm').click(function(e) {

    });
</script>
```

Comment: check with  "app-name-form" instead of app-name-form inside script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dashes are not legal in javascript variable names. The interpreter will not parse them correctly. Because of this you have to work around the interpreter.

Do something like:

```
rules: {
    "app-name-form": "required"
}
```

instead of your original (without the quotes):

```
rules: {
    app-name-form: "required"
}
```

Comment: Thank you, totally forgot about the dashes in JS

Answer (score 0):

You can not use the minus sign in the names of javascript variables because it is the `Math subtraction operator`, to make it work just put the id between `''`.

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submit-form").validate({
        rules: {
            'app-name-form': "required"
        },
        messages: {
            'app-name-form': {
                required: "Enter name pls"
            }
        }
    });
    });

    $('#saveForm').click(function(e) {

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.15.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<form id="submit-form">
  <label for="app-name-form">
    <input name="app-name-form" type="text" id="app-name-form"/>
    <div class="label-text">App Name</div>
  </label>

  <label for="team-name-form">
    <input type="text" id="team-name-form" name="team-name-form"/>
    <div class="label-text">Team</div>
  </label>

    <label>
          <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Submit" name="saveForm" id="saveForm"/>
    </label>

</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! Accepted answer based on which was first. :)